# JQuery - random .replace() error

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, random, replace

I have problem with random .replace(), it allways display same random number, i am trying to replace $random$ with a different random number.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10'
  ]
  $("#present-users").children('li.present-user').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).find('img')[0].title);
  });
  var random = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  var text = "$random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$ $random$".replace(/\$random\$/g, random);
  alert(text)
});
```

**[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kxo60agm/)**

Thanks,
Nikola

Comment: @daniel i want to replace every $random$ with a different number, not same number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use the [`.replace(regex, function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) overload:

```
str.replace(/\$random\$/g, function() {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxo60agm/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are calling Math.random() only once, and using this answer several times.

One way to fix this would be to make random a function, e.g.

```
var arr = [10,20,30];
var random = function(){return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)};
alert(random());
alert(random());
alert(arr[random()]);
```